# HTML5 placeholders acting as values

Tags: jquery, html

A client of mine using HTML5 placeholders in their contact form but all of a sudden they've begun acting like values and allowing the form to be submitted without all the required fields being populated.

Is there a workaround for this?

[Here's an example link](http://www.graphictankclients.co.uk/brunch/contact-us) of that helps (Name, Phone number and Email) are all required fields but only email gives an error if it isn't filled in properly

Comment: Show us here your validation method/script

Comment: Works fine here. What browser does the customer use?

Comment: There is the so called "html5 form validation". [Google it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+form+validation)

Answer (score 1):

You use aria-required instead of `required`.

Also have a look at HTML5 Form Validation:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

This site contains useful examples like:

```
<input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
```

**EDIT:**

Please remember that HTML5 Validation should only be used for the sake of userfriendlyness (usability, nicer/visual error handling). If the browser doesn't support html5 (like a browser wouldn't support js) there is no validation performed. So still use backend validation!

Comment: My client is using a Wordpress plugin so I'm not sure if it's possible to use change the markup without modifying the core files.

Comment: Ok, have a look at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/html5-boilerplate/), [Add an HTML5 Contact Form to Your WordPress Site](http://wpmu.org/add-an-html5-contact-form-to-your-wordpress-site/) and [How to insert HTML5 form validation attributes into WordPress](http://8tut.com/how-to-insert-html5-form-validation-attributes-and-add-more-fields-into-wordpress-comment-form/). **Have a look and let me know what you think.**

Answer (score 1):

You have a function in your `custom.js` that sets the value to the placeholder text:

```
 if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
     $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
 }
```

but the function that deletes this at submit is commented out:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
        //$(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
    });
```

I also think that the `$.support.placeholder` you use there is not defined.

Comment: Looking at that part of code (Most of this website was done by someone else) it looks like that section was to target Internet Explorer... yet I'm having issues in both Firefox and Chrome too

Comment: I see this in the code `if(!$.support.placeholder) {` which I take to mean any browser that does NOT support placeholders? (Can you tell I'm more of a PHP man?)

Comment: Theres no `placeholder` test in `jQuery.support`. If this not defined somewhere `(!$.support.placeholder)` will return `true`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/